# Update Post Status On Woocommerce Payment Complete

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, subscription

I have the following piece of code which publishes a user's post as long as they have purchased a subscription package and it changes the status of the post to draft as soon as their package has expired. I am just wondering how do I edit it so that the user can create a post and the post is automatically set to draft and then the status of the post is updated to published as soon as the user has completed the payment for a package? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if ( ! in_array( $new_status, array( 'active', 'trial' ) ) ) {
        $user_limits = stm_get_post_limits( $user_id );

        $posts_args = array(
            'orderby'        => 'post_date',
            'order'          => 'DESC',
            'post_type'      => 'listings',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => - 1,
            'meta_query'     => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'stm_car_user',
                    'value'   => $user_id,
                    'compare' => ''
                )
            ),
            'fields'         => 'ids'
        );

        $user_posts = get_posts( $posts_args );
        if ( count( $user_posts ) > $user_limits['posts_allowed'] ) {
            array_splice( $user_posts, 0, $user_limits['posts_allowed'] );
            foreach ( $user_posts as $user_post ) {
                $draft_post = array(
                    'ID'          => $user_post,
                    'post_status' => 'draft'
                );
                wp_update_post( $draft_post );
            }
        }

        /*Change user back to private if not admin*/
        if(!user_can($user_id, 'manage_options')) {
            wp_update_user( array(
                'ID'   => $user_id,
                'role' => 'privateseller'
            ) );
        }

    } else {
        /*If plan includes dealeship, change user role to dealer*/
        if ( $role == 'dealer' ) {
            wp_update_user( array(
                'ID'   => $user_id,
                'role' => 'stm_dealer'
            ) );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered the WooCommerce action `woocommerce_order_status_completed` which is called when the order status is changed to `wc-completed`? It is called with the order id and the order object (instance of WC_Order) from which you can get the details of the order.

Comment: I have this issue fixed using the method you suggested thank you. I just forgot to edit the question to say it was solved thanks.